# Numpy: Replace remaining columns of a row after certain index in each row

Tags: python, numpy

I have some data captured in a 3 dimensional ndarray, with the dimensions of: time tick, number of samples, and number of values per sample.

Through a previous operation, I know that at a certain time tick, whether each sample number becomes invalid. In cases where this never occurs, the number is set to -1.  In other cases, it indicates the time tick at which the samples become invalid.

What I'd like to be able to do is either blank out the rest of the columns, either by setting columns including and to the right of the invalid data to nans, or by using some masking or indexing technique that results in keeping only the data to the left.

I've read about or found references to similar problems involving fancy indexing, `slice()`, boolean arrays, and masked arrays, but I'm not seeing a way to accomplish my goal.

```py
import numpy as np

# dimensions are timestep, sample, and values per sample.  To make it easy, let's 
# do 3 time steps, 4 samples, and 2 values per sample.
data = np.array( [
    [ # Timestep 0
        [ 1, 2 ],  # Sample 1
        [ 3, 4 ],  #        2
        [ 5, 6 ],  #        3
        [ 7, 8 ],  #        4
    ],
    [ # Timestep 1
        [ 1, 2 ], 
        [ 3, 4 ],
        [ 5, 6 ],
        [ 7, 8 ],
    ],
    [ # Timestep 2
        [ 1, 2 ], 
        [ 3, 4 ],
        [ 5, 6 ],
        [ 7, 8 ],
    ],
])
```

Each sample may become invalid at a timestep.  If the timestep is never invalid, the value is -1.

```
invalid_at = [ 
        0, # becomes invalid at timestep 0
        2, #                             2
        1, #                             1 
        -1 # Never is invalid
        ]
```

If for example we replace invalid values with nan, then the resulting array should look like

```
data = np.array( [
    [ # Timestep 0
        [ n, n ],  # Sample 1
        [ 3, 4 ],  #        2
        [ 5, 6 ],  #        3
        [ 7, 8 ],  #        4
    ],
    [ # Timestep 1
        [ n, n ], 
        [ 3, 4 ],
        [ n, n ],
        [ 7, 8 ],
    ],
    [ # Timestep 2
        [ n, n ], 
        [ n, n ],
        [ n, n ],
        [ 7, 8 ],
    ],
])
```

The chief difficulty I'm running into is that I have the start index, but I can't find a way to create a slice (using fancy indexing or otherwise) that will let me assign to it.

For example, the following doesn't work:

```
data[ :, invalid_at:-1, : ] = np.nan
```

What I was hoping would happen is that the invalid at array would be evaluated and generate a per-row slice.

I could do this with a for loop, but I'd prefer to keep it vectorized for speed and later scalability. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the number of samples always small? E.g. hundreds, or even low thousands.

Comment: Its currently in the low thousands, but I expect it to grow.  (Btw, this is a generic explanation of my actual problem that gets at the root issue in a hopefully understandable way.)

Comment: The problem with "generic" solutions to optimization is that optimization, by its nature, is very case specific.

Comment: There's far too much detail for me to communicate my full problem in a way that will be understandable to a generic audience.  Coming up with a salient minimal working example is exactly what I should be doing.  :o)   Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of possible ways to do this. The main issue is that the index you are trying to apply is ragged.

If the number of samples is small, you can loop over them with relatively little additional overhead. This option is extremely straightforward, and supports simple slice indexing, which is generally the fastest kind of indexing since it doesn't require additional copies of data or masks:

```
for sample, step in enumerate(invalid_at):
    if step < 0:
        continue
    data[step:, sample, :] = np.nan
```

If you really need to do this in one step, you can construct a mask and apply it. The array has dimensions (timestep, sample, x). The mask only needs the first two dimensions. You need to set up a condition like "if an element is at timestep `t` and sample is greater than or equal to `invalid_at[t]`, set the element to `True`. The condition can be applied to a pair of broadcasted arrays: one for timestep and one for sample:

```
trange = np.arange(data.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 1)
srange = np.array(invalid_at).reshape(1, -1)
srange[srange == -1] = data.shape[0]
mask = (trange >= srange)
data[mask, :] = np.nan
```

This will only work if you explicitly set `dtype=np.float` or similar for `data`, since the currently defined integer to does not support NaNs.

Comment: Thank you!  That works quite nicely.  I suppose I could switch the mask around to only accept trange <= srange... and then perform operations such as sum / mean on the masked array.  This would save the step of actually writing the nans to the array and may lead to higher performance.  If you haven't already, you should consider writing up a blog post somewhere describing working with ragged arrays like this.  :)

Comment: @jrjbertram. The application is too specific to your use case, and the solution it too trivial to discuss, in my opinion. If you have a blog yourself though, it may be worth writing this up on your end, with the details of the application.

Comment: @jrjbertram. Please do not edit answers with significant modifications. SO if for future readers as much as (if not more than) for your benefit. Adding a specific example does not materially improve my answer in that context.

Comment: SO offers the edit feature... soooo... it's available for use.  Also, I extended the answer for everyone's benefit, as there may be a performance advantage if the number of writes of nan's is large.  It does materially improve the answer in that it provides a secondary implementation alternative.  If you don't like that I did it, that's cool and my apologies.  It seemed more appropriate to build on your answer than to alter my question with the alternative implementation.  Cheers and thanks again.